# How do I increment the static variable and then assign it to the instance variable?

Tags: java

```
public abstract class BankAccount {

    private static int nextAccBalance = 12345678;

    private double balance;
    private int accountNumber;
    private Customer owner;
    private AccountType type;

    public BankAccount(double balance, Customer owner, AccountType type) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.type = type;
    }

    abstract void deposit(double amount);
    abstract void withdraw(double amount);
    abstract void monthEnd();

}
```

I need to increment the static variable of nextAccNum by 100  and then assign it to the accountNumber instance variable but I can't seem to understand how :/ could, someone help me/explain me.

Comment: At what point would you like to do that? Where exactly? from withing an instance? independently of instances?

Comment: There is no `nextAccNum` static variable.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this is

```
private static int nextAccNum = 12345678;

nextAccNum += 100;
accountNumber = nextAccNum;
```

a more cryptic way is

```
accountNumber = (nextAccNum += 100);
```

however a more thread safe way is

```
private static final AtomicInteger nextAccNum = new AtomicInteger(12345678);

accountNumber = nextAccNum.addAndGet(100);
```

Comment: Thanks for help ^^ I am blue in programming so basic things are difficult for me. This surely helped a lot :D

Comment: @FilipBrzuska I think you mean *new* to programming.

Comment: :) yea, exactly

Comment: @FilipBrzuska it is much harder if English is not your first language.

Comment: it certainly is but the "blue" was not a mistake, I tend to say that when I am clueless about something ^^ it's a reference from a song I'm blue by Eiffel 65 from 1999. Sorry for confusing you, I tend to do that a lot.

Comment: @FilipBrzuska I liked that song. ;)